# Why can't I read those MTLTexture pixels?

Tags: swift, metal

I am trying to get the pixels of a `MTLTexture` this way:

```
let pixelCount = compareTexture.width * compareTexture.height

let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, compareTexture.width, compareTexture.height)  

var textureComponentsArray = Array<float4>(repeating: float4(0), count: pixelCount)

textureComponentsArray.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
   compareTexture.getBytes($0.baseAddress!, bytesPerRow: (MemoryLayout<float4>.size * compareTexture.width), from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)
}

print(textureComponentsArray.first!)
```

Unfortunately most elements are either NaN or equal to the values which I initialised my textureComponentsArray with. For instance this code prints :

```
float4(nan, nan, nan, nan)
```

I am on macOS and my MTLTexture has those properties:

```
let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
textureDescriptor.width = imageTexture.width
textureDescriptor.height = imageTexture.height
textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = imageTexture.pixelFormat
textureDescriptor.resourceOptions = .storageModeManaged
textureDescriptor.storageMode = .managed
textureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget, .shaderRead, .shaderWrite]
```

I do use the managed storage mode so the data should be available to CPU, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Thank you.

**EDIT :**
I am trying to use :

```
blitCommandEncoder.synchronize(resource: compareTexture)
```

And I do wait the command buffer to complete but there is still the issue.

Comment: What is `imageTexture.pixelFormat`? I would expect it to be something like `rgba32Float` based on the code above. If it's actually something like `rgba8Unorm`, you should expect that each pixel consists of four bytes, not four floats. Depending on the texture contents, it's quite possible that treating a 32-bit pixel value that is actually four 8-bit components as a float could produce every imaginable pathological float value (NaNs, denorms, etc.) Put another way: `getBytes` doesn't do the same conversion `read` or `sample` in a shader does; it copies data in the texture's "native" format.

Comment: @warrenm Thank you for your help, I just checked the type of my texture it is `bgra8Unorm`, so I changed it to `rgba32Float` and now it works perfectly! Apart from changing the type of a texture, what is the recommended way to accessing to those components as I wanted? Now that I converted my texture to the `rgba32Float` these are Float components but I don't understand what their type was when it was still a `bgra8Unorm` texture? Could I have simply initialised a Swift array with the same type as those and then convert it to the type I wish or is this more complicated than that? Thank you! :)

Comment: Certainly, you could have initialized the array to be of type `[UInt8]`, then every four consecutive elements would comprise one pixel. `bgra8unorm` implies one byte per component, where the values [0,255] are normalized to [0,1] when read/sampled.

Answer (score 2):

I needed an answer for this question for iOS. I'm leaving here the extension I wrote for my needs.

```swift
import Metal

extension MTLTexture {
  func getPixels<T> (_ region: MTLRegion? = nil, mipmapLevel: Int = 0) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T> {
    let fromRegion  = region ?? MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
    let width       = fromRegion.size.width
    let height      = fromRegion.size.height
    let bytesPerRow = MemoryLayout<T>.stride * width
    let data        = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: bytesPerRow * height)

    self.getBytes(data, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: fromRegion, mipmapLevel: mipmapLevel)
    return data
  }
}
```

You can simply call the function. But remember that you are responsible for deallocating the memory used for the data object.

You can read the pixels if they are in different formats too. For a `MTLPixelFormat.rgba32Float` texture I'm retrieving the data as:

```swift
let pixels: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32> = texture.getPixels()
defer {
  pixels.deallocate()
}

let capacity = texture.width * texture.height * MemoryLayout<Float32>.stride

for i in stride(from: 0, to: capacity, by: 4) {
  let l     = pixels[i + 0]
  let a     = pixels[i + 1]
  let b     = pixels[i + 2]
  let alpha = pixels[i + 3]
}
```